# Determine user preference for target="_blank", new window or tab

Tags: html

I know that `target="_blank"`, whether it opens a new window or a new tab, is up to the user's preference. I'm not trying to change that.

What I am trying to determine is, is it possible to know what the user's setting is? I want to create a new button with a label that either says "Open In New Window" or "Open In New Tab", depending on what will happen based on the site visitor's preference. I don't want the button to say "Open In New Window" if the user's preference is to open links in a new tab, or vice-versa, so that they aren't misled as to what's going to happen.

I could have the button say "Open In New Window/Tab", but I'm trying to be a little less sloppy than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible to access a user's browser configuration and change your html code according to his preferences. So your options are:

- Picking either "Open In New Window", "Open In New Window/Tab", "Open In New Tab" or any other name for the button
- Not using `target="_blank"` at all, *since user can easily open your link in a new window/tab just by pressing his mousewheel or right-clicking it*

Maybe that is not that big of an issue after all ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to give novice users the option to open something in a new window explicitly (so, not expecting them to know that they can specifically open the link in a new tab/window), that's why I was wanting to cater the text to their settings.